# Making an XSLT method behave differently at different times (maybe with a parameter?)

Tags: xml, xslt

So I have the line of code:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/MyQuery/Arguments/PhoneNumber" />
```

That gets the phone number value from the XML, from whatever phone number was entered in the Phone Number field of my form.  Let's call it 555-867-5309.

When the line above is run, it calls the template with the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="PhoneNumber">
    <xsl:if test="(. != '')">
        <xsl:call-template name="StringBreakUp"> <!-- Area Code -->
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
            <xsl:with-param name="current-position" select="2" />
            <xsl:with-param name="remaining-length" select="4" />
            <xsl:with-param name="max-size" select="5" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="fieldSeparator" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

It grabs the area code of the phone number, so it ends up with the 555, like I want it to.

But I need a way to then get the phone number proper, that is to say, the 867-5309.  It can be grabbed like this:

```
<xsl:template match="PhoneNumber2">
    <xsl:if test="(. != '')">
        <xsl:call-template name="StringBreakUp"> <!-- Phone Number -->
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
            <xsl:with-param name="current-position" select="6" />
            <xsl:with-param name="remaining-length" select="4" />
            <xsl:with-param name="max-size" select="14" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="fieldSeparator" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately, I can't call that template like I did the first one with:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/MyQuery/Arguments/PhoneNumber2" />
```

because there is nothing in the XML called PhoneNumber2.

The best I can come up with is to call

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/MyQuery/Arguments/PhoneNumber" />
```

twice.  But, **and here's the problem**, I cannot come up with a way for it to differentiate between the time it needs to grab the area code (first time calling the template) and the time it needs to grab the phone number proper (second time it calls the method).

So what I'm looking for is something to the effect of:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/MyQuery/Arguments/PhoneNumber" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="/MyQuery/Arguments/PhoneNumber" />

<xsl:template match="NewPhoneNumber">
    <xsl:if test="(. != '')"> **AND FIRST TIME CALLING THIS METHOD**
        <xsl:call-template name="StringBreakUp"> <!-- Area Code -->
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
            <xsl:with-param name="current-position" select="2" />
            <xsl:with-param name="remaining-length" select="4" />
            <xsl:with-param name="max-size" select="5" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="fieldSeparator" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="(. != '')"> **AND NOT FIRST TIME REACHING THIS METHOD**
        <xsl:call-template name="StringBreakUp"> <!-- Phone Number -->
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
            <xsl:with-param name="current-position" select="6" />
            <xsl:with-param name="remaining-length" select="4" />
            <xsl:with-param name="max-size" select="14" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="fieldSeparator" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

But I can't figure out how to use the:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/MyQuery/Arguments/PhoneNumber" />
```

with a parameter so I can distinguish which time we're going through the entire phone number.

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="Arguments">
    <xsl:call-template name="fieldSeparator" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/MyQuery/Arguments/Name" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/MyQuery/Arguments/PhoneNumber" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/MyQuery/Arguments/PhoneNumber" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name"> 
    <xsl:if test="(. != '')">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        <xsl:call-template name="fieldSeparator" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PhoneNumber">
    <xsl:if test="(. != '')">
        <xsl:call-template name="StringBreakUp"> <!-- Area Code -->
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
            <xsl:with-param name="current-position" select="2" />
            <xsl:with-param name="remaining-length" select="4" />
            <xsl:with-param name="max-size" select="5" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="fieldSeparator" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="PhoneNumber2">
    <xsl:if test="(. != '')">
        <xsl:call-template name="StringBreakUp"> <!-- Phone Number -->
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
            <xsl:with-param name="current-position" select="6" />
            <xsl:with-param name="remaining-length" select="4" />
            <xsl:with-param name="max-size" select="14" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="fieldSeparator" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML**

```
< MyQuery >

< Arguments >

    < Name >NNN</ Name >

    < PhoneNumber >(555)867-5309</ PhoneNumber >

</ Arguments >

</ MyQuery >
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**
    NNN 555 555

**DESIRED OUTPUT**
    NNN 555 867-5309

Comment: Please present your problem from a slightly different angle: Show a small XML input (with elements like `PhoneNumber`, `Arguments` and so on). Then, show a _complete_ XSLT stylesheet (don't worry if it does not work) and show what result you expect from the transformation - again, not by describing it, but by showing either XML or text output.

Comment: Added the details.  As you can see, it calls the PhoneNumber template twice, as expected.  I need the stuff in PhoneNumber and the stuff in PhoneNumber2 to both happen, though, but I can't call PhoneNumber2 in the arguments section of the XSLT.

Comment: It fails straight out -- `No template exists named StringBreakUp` and the same for `fieldSeparator`. Please supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah, those are in separate files entirely.  They're things that we use all over the project.  Thank you for the link, I will read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question **as asked** - i.e. how to apply two different templates to the same node - is to use *modes*.

For example:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="MyQuery/Arguments/PhoneNumber" mode="area"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="MyQuery/Arguments/PhoneNumber" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PhoneNumber" mode="area">
    <!-- code to extract the area -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PhoneNumber">
    <!-- code to extract the number -->
</xsl:template>
```

Another option is to use named templates (directly), e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="pNum" select="MyQuery/Arguments/PhoneNumber"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="get-area">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$pnum"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name="get-number">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$pnum"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="get-area">
    <!-- code to extract the area -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="get-number">
    <!-- code to extract the number -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Modes!  Yes, that did exactly the thing I was looking for!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Until now, I honestly fail to see why your code should be that complicated. For simple string manipulations (like getting only part of a string) there is no need for a named template.

Also, it seems to me there is no point in splitting up a string and retrieving both parts in complicated ways - only to output them one after another again.

**XML Input**

```
<MyQuery>
    <Arguments>
        <Name>NNN</Name>
        <PhoneNumber>(555)867-5309</PhoneNumber>
    </Arguments>
</MyQuery>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Arguments">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name,translate(PhoneNumber,'()','  '))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Text Output**

```
NNN 555 867-5309
```

Comment: That does indeed display both of them, but I need to keep them separate entities, not concatenated together.

Comment: @user3402743 Then perhaps you could explain _why_ you need to keep them separate and in what way? And respond to Jongware's comment? The named templates are missing from your code - nobody can reproduce your issue.

Comment: The form previously had two separate fields, one for area code and one for the phone number proper.  The two values were being sent separately to the client's system.  It was requested that the two values continue to be sent separately, but only using one field on the form.

Comment: @user3402743 Unfortunately, I do not know what fields or forms you are talking about - but it seems someone else correctly guessed what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

Like Matthias said in his answer, you are way overcomplicating things with separate templates or even params. Having said that below should do what you originally requested, i.e. different behaviour based on the parameter value. It might be useful to you for something else unless you have a reason why you can simplify your XSL.

I omitted irrelevant pieces from below XSL.

```
<xsl:template name="Arguments">
    <xsl:call-template name="fieldSeparator" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/MyQuery/Arguments/Name" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/MyQuery/Arguments/PhoneNumber" >
        <xsl:with-param name="areaCode">true</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/MyQuery/Arguments/PhoneNumber">
        <xsl:with-param name="areaCode">false</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PhoneNumber">
    <xsl:param name="areaCode" />
    <xsl:if test="(. != '')">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$areaCode='true'">
                <xsl:call-template name="StringBreakUp"> <!-- Area Code -->
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
                    <xsl:with-param name="current-position" select="2" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="remaining-length" select="4" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="max-size" select="5" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="StringBreakUp"> <!-- Phone Number -->
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
                    <xsl:with-param name="current-position" select="6" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="remaining-length" select="4" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="max-size" select="14" />
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="fieldSeparator" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="fieldSeparator" />
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for!  Except it tells me that "the variable or parameter 'areaCode' is either not defined or it is out of scope."

It's really close, but it's like the parameter isn't actually being passed.